# Install Laravel in legacy project

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to install Laravel in an old project.

I tried to place my existing project files from `/www` folder into `/public` folder.

Now I am facing some issues.

1) I tried to rename the Laravel's index.php to `laravel.php` and same in `.htaccess` but it did not work. I am doing this to avoid the conflict with my `index.php`

2) My project has following `/www/.htaccess` file and uses routing using `mod_rewrite_delegator.php` file. I have not idea how to handle this part.

If I user `myproject.com/events` this does not work but `myproject.com/events/dashboard.php` works. So I need Laravel to find the route from my old project first and then under Laravel routing.

Here are my existing `.htaccess` code

```
Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks


RewriteEngine on


# quick links
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !/user_files/
RewriteRule ^([^\.\?]+)$        /mod_rewrite_delegator.php?keyword=$1   [QSA,L]


ErrorDocument 404 /http_404.php
```

Thank you

Comment: Don't mix the files; merging them into your existing project will only cause problems. Create either a subdirectory or an entirely separate directory for Laravel and update its configuration to reflect that.

Comment: @kungphu How should I do it? I need the URL to go to `mode_rewrite_delegator.php` first and if not found then look into laravel.

Comment: It's been too long since I worked with Apache configuration, but you should be able to write a separate RewriteRule that sends, e.g., `/laravel/*` requests to Laravel in a different directory. Making it contingent on not matching a valid URL in your other project is asking for collisions; keeping their entirely separate is much better.